# Mapstruct - mapper object needs valuemapping of an object field

Tags: mapstruct

I have an object `A` which I am trying to map to `B`. Now this `A` has an enum named `field1` with some values. I want to map them using `@ValueMappings` to someother enum value in `B`. Below is my code till now:

```
@Mapping(source = "field1", target = "field1", nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = IGNORE)
@Mapping(source = "field2", target = "field2", nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = IGNORE)
@ValueMappings({
    @ValueMapping(source = "field1.some1", target = "diff1"),
    @ValueMapping(source = "field1.some2", target = "diff1"),
    @ValueMapping(source = "field1.some3", target = "diff1"),
    @ValueMapping(source = "field1.some4", target = "diff2"),
})
B map(A a);
```

When I try to compile this, I get the error:

```
error: The following constants from the property "A.field1 field1" enum have no corresponding constant in the "B field1" enum and must be be mapped via adding additional mappings: diff1, diff2.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to do something like this:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",  uses = {SomeUtil.class}, unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface Mapper {
    @Mapping(source = "field1", target = "field1", nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = IGNORE)
    @Mapping(source = "field2", target = "field2", nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = IGNORE)
    B map(A a);
}
```

And in SomeUtil.class:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface SomeUtil {

    @ValueMappings({
        @ValueMapping(source = "field1.some1", target = "diff1"),
        @ValueMapping(source = "field1.some2", target = "diff1"),
        @ValueMapping(source = "field1.some3", target = "diff1"),
        @ValueMapping(source = "field1.some4", target = "diff2"),
    })
    b.field1 map(a.field1 field);
}
```